# CSS: width: 100% won't fill the parent's width in certain browsers

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, create-react-app

Currently i am working on an interactive card template to display content in my web app, the goal is to have "mask" that starts from 30% from the top, stretches to the bottom end and fills the full width of the parent (banner class), i have the following classes in my CSS file for these components.

```
.banner{
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: #F7AE00;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 250px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(26, 55, 80);
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: flex;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.mask {
    z-index: 6;
    /* clip-path: polygon(30% 0%,
                  100% 0%,
                  100% 100%,
                 20% 100%);  */
    background: linear-gradient(to right top,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
                rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.1)),
                gray;

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;

    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;

    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 100%;
    transition: height 300ms ease-in-out, opacity 200ms ease-in-out;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    border: 2px solid rgb(26, 55, 80);
    border-top-width: 3px;
}
```

My cards look and behave good, but in certain browsers (like Opera GX) the mask won't fill the full banner width, i tried different solutions for this, and some times i can make it to fill the width in these browsers, but again i get this issue when i play with the border of the banner class.

I guess my question is: Is this a compatibility issue or there must be statements that will fit my porpuse no matter the browser the client is using?

EDIT:

These are the dimension i'm getting at Opera GX (Firefox, Chrome and Edge scale the mask without problems).

[dimension gotten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqudU.png)

also from my research, it seems that the statements with the '-o-' prefix are no longer supported for targeting Opera browsers. I'm not 100% secure of this, but while trying to solve this issue i couldn't make use of the '-o-' prefix (it just didn't apply these statements). Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Note that i updated the css code provided, however the issue persists in the current version.

Looking at the dimensions, 246 + 2 + 2 should result on 250 which is the width of the banner, but for some reason mask does not fill the full width when displayed on Opera, here's a screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLzk9.png)

maybe the 2 px border is not behaving like it should.

Comment: Are you sure it's not 100% width but just hidden - `left: auto` seems ambiguous and maybe opera isn't starting it left at the left edge?

Comment: @Pete i don't understand your first sentence. 'left: auto' combined with the other position statements was my first thought to place the mask on the bottom right corner of the banner, removing this line does not seem to have any consecuences, for what i've seen.
Edited the post to update the code and add an img for the dimensions i'm getting.